# Probably simple, but i don't get it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

Now I was doing some physics and I got to this equation, task is solved but i don't get this part... So is it possible to get for

$$\frac{m_1(v^2_1-w_1^2)}{m_1(v_1+w_1)}=w_2$$
to
$v_1-w_1=w_2$.

Answer (score 7):

Use

$$\frac{m_1 (v_1^2 - w_1^2)}{m_1 (v_1 + w_1)} = \frac{m_1 (v_1 - w_1)(v_1 + w_1)}{m_1 (v_1 + w_1)} = v_1 - w_1$$

Comment: that was really fast :)

Comment: @Ragnar:  The difference of squares shows up often.  It is useful to recognize its factorization.

Comment: oh of course, thank you

Comment: @RossMillikan, I know how to solve it, but to write it down within a minute from asking is fast.